# Cant display marker on google map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to display multiple markers on my test page. I have a JSON:

```
var myJson = 
{
"hotels": [
    {
      "hotelCode" : "1",
      "isAvailable" : "true",
      "latitude" : "53.427901",
      "longitude" : "-6.233612",
      "price" : "99"      
    },
etc.
```

and this is my JS code:

var map;

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.345897,-6.269204);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(myJson.hotels[0].latitude, myJson.hotels[0].longitude);
  console.log(myJson.hotels[0].latitude, myJson.hotels[0].longitude);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng2,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  console.log(marker);
  var key = 0;
  for(key in myJson.hotels)
  {
      var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myJson.hotels[key].latitude + "," + myJson.hotels[key].longitude);

      var i =  new google.maps.Marker(
      {
        position: newLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      }); 

  }          

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My problem is:
  - marker with hardcoded (myLatlng) - displays fine
  - markey2 dis not displayed
  - markers from 'for' loop are not displayed.

```
console.log(myJson.hotels[0].latitude, myJson.hotels[0].longitude);
```

gives me:

53.427901 -6.233612

Comment: Your code works for me [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CbH57/1/)

Comment: code started to work, when I replaced
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("53.345897","-6.269204");
with
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myJson.hotels[0].latitude, myJson.hotels[0].longitude);

Comment: Ok, here the answer: map wast zoomed too much to see the other pins. School boy error